# Showing thousand separator in org-mode spreadsheets

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to configure org-mode spreadsheets to show thousand separators? I would like 1000 to be shown as 1,000.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. First define the function **group-number**:

```
(defun group-number (num &optional size char)
    "Format NUM as string grouped to SIZE with CHAR."
    ;; Based on code for `math-group-float' in calc-ext.el
    (let* ((size (or size 3))
           (char (or char ","))
           (str (if (stringp num)
                    num
                  (number-to-string num)))
            ;; omitting any trailing non-digit chars
            ;; NOTE: Calc supports BASE up to 36 (26 letters and 10 digits ;)
           (pt (or (string-match "[^0-9a-zA-Z]" str) (length str))))
      (while (> pt size)
        (setq str (concat (substring str 0 (- pt size))
                          char
                          (substring str (- pt size)))
              pt (- pt size)))
      str))
```

from: [Emacs Cookbook - put commas in numbers](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc23)

```
Next, use it in your formula:
|           |       |             |
|-----------+-------+-------------|
|      2000 |  3100 |       5,100 |
|        11 |    22 |          33 |
| 111221212 | 29996 | 111,251,208 |
|           |       |           0 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(group-number (+ $1 $2));N
```

Here we are using the **group-number** function to format the result of an emacs lisp form - rather than using the calc formula syntax.

Comment: Yes, this does work in the simple case, but I use formatting like %.2f and that does not work with group-number. Also, if I add a fourth column in your example and define it to be $4=$3+$3, the calculation is not done correctly. So doing further calculations based on formatted numbers does not work.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. What we need is the display code doing this, not changing the result to be a numeric string with commas. Calc does have this feature of grouping digits when displaying the result (see [http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/calc_7.html#SEC162]), but I can't see how to use that here.

Comment: @Jeffrey DeLeo one could use your `group-number` function to add an overlay instead of using it as a formula.  The caveat is, overlays might deteriorate performance for really large tables.